# Completely remove MATE desktop from Ubuntu MATE 16.04

Tags: cinnamon, mate

I have Ubuntu MATE 16.04 on my laptop. I have installed Cinnamon 3.0 using [embrosyn's PPA](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/04/how-to-install-cinnamon-30-in-ubuntu.html)

However, now when I try to login to my laptop, every time I have to select the Cinnamon desktop manually, which is very frustrating.

How can I completely remove MATE and make Cinnamon default desktop environment?

Comment: Llightdm (login manager) should remember the last choosen session - so as far as i know there should be no need to select Cinnamon over and over again. what login-manager are you using?

Comment: That should be the default one. I didn't change anything. Installed it from Ubuntu Mate 16.04 ISO

Comment: You could remove most MATE related packages simply by running `sudo apt remove ubuntu-mate-*`

Answer (score 23):

To completely remove MATE:

**Uninstall mate-desktop**

To remove just mate-desktop package itself from Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus) execute on terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove mate-desktop
```

**Uninstall mate-desktop and it's dependent packages**

To remove the mate-desktop package and any other dependant package which are no longer needed from Ubuntu Xenial.

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove mate-desktop
```

**Purging mate-desktop**

If you also want to delete configuration and/or data files of mate-desktop from Ubuntu Xenial then this will work:

```
sudo apt-get purge mate-desktop
```

To delete configuration and/or data files of mate-desktop and it's dependencies from Ubuntu Xenial then execute:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove mate-desktop
```

REF:[LINK](https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/mate-desktop?action=remove)

Answer (score 0):

## First, check what is going to be removed

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep .mate.
```

## If you are ok with it, run this command

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge mate*
```

## Command explanation

```
# dpkg -l       lists all installed packages
# grep .mate.   filters, so that only packages with keyword mate within their names, listed
# purge         removes mentioned package
# autoremove    tries to remove dependency packages
```