# Remove mate-gdm from ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, mate

I have installed ubuntu 17.10 and installed complete mate-desktop-environment. Now I want to completely remove mate. I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784905/completely-remove-mate-desktop-from-ubuntu-mate-16-04) but mate-gdm still there. So, how to remove it?

Comment: Could you post the exact commands you used?

Comment: Exact commands are:<br/>sudo apt remove mate-desktop<br/>sudo apt remove --auto-remove mate-desktop<br/>sudo apt purge mate-desktop<br/>sudo apt purge --auto-remove mate-desktop                                         @MarcVanhoomissen